# Infinite scroll + Tooltips

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, tooltip, infinite-scroll

I'm currently using Responsive Mobile-Friendly Tooltip plugin on a wordpress theme which also uses Infinite scroll. All the elements that are loaded at the same time that the page is loaded show a tooltip when Hover. Yet all the new elements that are added while scrolling down are not recognized by the plugin and show now tooltip.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and perhaps found any solution?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a callback in the infinite scroll, like:

```
jQuery('#div').infinitescroll({
    ....
},
function(){
    jQuery('.tooltip').tooltip()
});
```